# Wishing a long life to someone holding a Torah scroll

Tags: blessing, sefer-torah, age, yiddish

For *Kol Nidre*, Torah scrolls are removed from their cabinet and held at the reading table. I have heard people bless the people holding the scrolls with *lange yaren*, long years, i.e. a long life.

Similarly, on *Simchas Tora*, people walk/dance around the synagogue holding Torah scrolls. Again, I've heard people bless them with *lange yaren*.

Where does this come from and why is it done? (Obviously, it's always nice to bless people with long lives, but why is it done here specifically?)

Comment: noblesse oblige.  sense of nobility obliges

Comment: would anyone care to comment on the correct form of this blessing, perhaps  "צו לאַנגע יאָר"?

Comment: Never heard of this, but my guess is that since the honour could cause jealousy (and as a result Ayin Hora), one counters that by actively blessing the honorees. Just a guess.