# Tsu Langeh Yaren?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

People often mention when referring to an elderly person the Yiddish phrase "Tsu langeh yaren" - "Tsu lengthens life" ([example](https://yugntruf.org/about-us/who-we-are/?lang=en)). Some even say it about younger people as well - [if they sneeze](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/931721/jewish/Why-say-gezuntheit-after-a-sneeze.htm) or [hold a *sefer Torah*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77165/3). We know that Tsu has been in the practice of lengthening for centuries (cf. middle of [this page](http://www.genetickanji.com/docs/pronunciation-change-rules-japanese.html)), but when and how did its power extend from letters to human life?

Please include 引用.

### Apologia:

I know. I know. This is about *Tsu*s, not *Tsudaism*. But I think it belongs on this site because there are vast *nafka*s *mina lahalacha* according to the opinion that Tsu wrote the תורה. See [this Ⓤ article](https://www.ou.org/torah/parsha/rabbi-sacks-on-parsha/a_journey_of_a_thousand_miles/), for example:

> the Torah...came...from...Lao-Tzu, the Chinese Sage

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Great question! I love your OU quote. That's just perfect :)

Comment: this question is pure tshushim   i hate it

Answer (score 1):

I can't say much about Tsu, in general. But one form os "tsu", namely shia-tsu is a form of massage that uses extended finger pressure on certain parts of the body.

[Wikiepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiatsu) explains:

> The Japanese Ministry of Health defines shiatsu as “a form of
>   manipulation by thumbs, fingers and palms without the use of
>   instruments, mechanical or otherwise, to apply pressure to the human
>   skin to correct internal malfunctions, promote and maintain health,
>   and treat specific diseases.

So, the "Tsu" in your expression refers to shiatsu. The Japanese Health ministry seems to think that it keeps people healthy. Healthy people have longer lives, generally. While the end of the Wikipedia article says that there has been no evidence that supports this point, I can tell you myself that I have had several shiatsu treatments, and they are wonderful, and I do feel healthier for days, afterwards. As for whether it will lengthen my life, I guess you'll have to wait until after I'm dead for me to tell you.